# Why does counting messages on MSMQ returns 0 when using Powershell Method?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wmi, msmq

I'm developing a WCF service running on IIS and I need to count the messages i = for each private queue in MSMQ. The fastest way seems to be the powershell method.

The benchmark is here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/346575/Message-Queue-Counting-Comparisions)

When debugging on Visual Studio 2012, it works great but when deployed on my local IIS 7.5 server, it returns 0.

Here is the method I'm using:

```
private int GetPowerShellCount()
{
    return GetPowerShellCount(".\\private$\pingpong", Environment.MachineName, "", "");
}

private  int GetPowerShellCount(string queuePath, string machine,string username, string password)
{
    var path = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\CIMv2", machine);
    ManagementScope scope;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
            scope = new ManagementScope(path);
    }
    else
    {
        var options = new ConnectionOptions {Username = username, Password = password};
        scope = new ManagementScope(path, options);
    }
    scope.Connect();
    if (queuePath.StartsWith(".\\")) queuePath=queuePath.Replace(".\\",string.Format("{0}\\",machine));

    string queryString = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue");
    var query = new ObjectQuery(queryString);
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    IEnumerable<int> messageCountEnumerable =
        from ManagementObject queue in searcher.Get()
        select (int)(UInt64)queue.GetPropertyValue("MessagesInQueue");
    //IEnumerable<string> messageCountEnumerable =
    //  from ManagementObject queue in searcher.Get()
    //  select (string)queue.GetPropertyValue("Name");
    var x = messageCountEnumerable.First();
    return x;
}
```

please note that I'm not using the user/pass params so it's all local (WCF service and MSMQ on the same machine).

Why it's returning 0 when deployed to IIS?
What do you think I should try out?

Comment: This code is c# not powershell. Or am I missing something?

Comment: hi, it's just called the powershell method but yes the code is in C# hence the C# tag. See the link I gave regarding why it's called the powershell  method. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be related to IIS specific behavior.

Have a look at Tom Hollander's blog: [MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx)

> In general, message queues can be called whatever you want. However
>   when you are hosting your MSMQ-enabled service in IIS 7 WAS, the queue
>   name *must* match the URI of your service's .svc file. In this example
>   we'll be hosting the service in an application called **MsmqService**
>   with an .svc file called **MsmqService.svc**, so the queue must be
>   called **MsmqService/MsmqService.svc**.